# Anatomically correct saiyan?

Tags: biology, science-in-society

A saiyan is a species that is biologically similiar to humans, except in one particular way. Every time they come back from the brink of death, their strength and speed increases. They also become more resistant to the thing that almost killed them. They love to fight, and their entire culture revolves around battle and war. At some point, they reach a level of power that allows them to transform into a more powerful version of themselves.

I need to create a "realistic" version of this race, and they must meet these set of criteria:

1. Their strength, speed, and agility increase after surviving a fatal attack, and become more resistant to damage.
2. After a lifetime of fighting, they can learn to overclock their bodies like a computer for a limited amount of time. They become stronger, faster, and tougher for that time period, but burn out quickly. It also takes them a long time to recover.

How can I biologically make this species to meet these requirements?

Comment: By definition, a fatal attack is one you don't survive.

Comment: @user1751825 What about loopholes where you're technically dead, but brought back afterwards?

Comment: Isn't that just a Pokemon? Pokemon can get stronger after fighting to the near-death, and they can transform by evolving. Why don't you ask about an anomaly correct Pokemon using the traits you described?

Answer (score 4):

For point 2, just use a ton of Adrenaline. It basically does everything you need to do.

For point 1, you can just give them a faster healing/evolving factor. This happens with people already, but on a small scale. Skin heals back stronger if constantly damaged. Your arms and legs get strong from constant usage and damage to the muscles. You can exaggerate that feature and add in a faster healing factor, maybe due to living in a very harsh environment.  People also gain experience from fighting so learning from the fight and analyzing it can also boost their perceived fighting level.

Comment: Yeah, I'm about to type this then you beat me to it.

Answer (score 3):

On a very limited scale, muscles already regenerate stronger when they are damaged - it is the mechanism behind exercise and how you get faster and stronger. Theoretically a race could have a much more effective version of this where muscles and bones regenerate faster upon receiving catastrophic damage. An alternate bone knitting mechanism could also cause stronger mends.

As for a "Super-Saiyan" mechanism - the adult members of your race could have a way to voluntarily trigger a massive rush of adrenaline and remove subconscious limiters on muscle strength. If you've heard stories of mothers lifting cars off their children, it's the same as that, but triggered on demand, rather than only under great stress.

Comment: Triggering adrenaline rush is possible normally as well. Either from mental exercise or physically by forcing short rapid breaths and tensing muscles.

Answer (score 1):

we already have something like this it's virus,

"Their strength, speed, and agility increase after surviving a fatal attack, and become more resistant to damage."

This happens when they figure to counterattack antibiotics

"After a lifetime of fighting, they can learn to super clock their bodies like a computer for a limited amount of time. They become stronger, faster, and tougher for th as t time period, but burn out quickly. It also takes them a long time to recover."

when patience is lost, they kill the host which basically a suicide

"How can I biologically make this species to meet these requirements?"

all you need to do is make it huge, consider giving the void human body to virus so that it can operate it like a controller.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, jkeasy M! Intersting first answer. If you have a moment, please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. You may also find [meta] and [The Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) useful. [Here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6388) is a meta post on the culture and style of Worldbuilding.SE, just to help you understand our scope and methods, and how we do things here. Have fun!

Comment: I think you are thinking about bacteria, not virii.

Comment: @Renan I think so, too. Especially since antibiotics do nothing to a virus. They kill of bacteria (unless they are resistant).

Comment: I suck at BIO, cannot be helped